# Why mark a `std::scoped_lock` variable as const?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I tried the "Code Analysis" feature of the latest Visual Studio 2017 release on a codebase which uses a number of `std::scoped_lock` variables like this:

```
void f()
{
    std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> my_lock(my_mutex);
    // ...
}
```

With the "Microsoft All Rules" configuration, Visual Studio suggests the following:

```
warning C26496: The variable 'my_lock' is assigned only once, mark it as const (con.4).
```

I normally use local `const` variables all the time, but I never felt it was necessary with types that don't allow modification anyway. A `std::scoped_lock` can only be constructed and destroyed. I guess Visual Studio just blindly applies a very general guideline here, but do I miss something? Would a `std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> const` ever allow the compiler to do something differently, or to detect an error during compilation?

Comment: I don't consider neither Visual Studio nor Microsoft in general a good source for such matters... In the given case, it even feels bad making the lock const; consider the class would provide lock and unlock functions, would these be const? Only then, I'd have the lock const...

Comment: I find applying `const` consistently helps me make sure I didn't forget and any variable that is left non-`const` is so for a reason. So even if it doesn't change anything I would make the lock const just to communicate that "I explicitly don't intend for this to be modified".

Comment: @Aconcagua: I'm not very happy with the "code analysis" feature, either. There are thousands of false positives and some clear bugs (e.g. with all enum class data members and all `std::optional` returns). Well, regarding a lock class with lock and unlock functions (like `std::unique_lock`) - that's a different case. `std::scoped_lock` does not have *any* member functions to call in your code.

Comment: "const variables all the time" - `f(g());` let's consider this as poorly readable, so we break it into `auto tmp = f(); g(tmp);` - and you'd have it const??? In my eyes, blindly following a more than questionable rule... And could even break with f returning and g accepting a (non-const) reference...

Comment: @ChristianHackl I know there are no members... Just because it *cannot* be modified because of lack of members does not make it const in my eyes. You are actively locking and unlocking, and these are no actions that would be provided in const functions, *if* these *were* available, so I wouldn't make the object const either, even *if* never modified...

Comment: @Aconcagua: Yes, I'd have it `const`, because then the compiler would detect a number of mistakes I might make. Of course, there may be some other considerations in special cases (e.g. moving).

Comment: @Aconcagua: I don't get what you are trying to say. Does it have anything to do with `std::scoped_lock`?

Comment: Might be unrelated but this specific feature [already had a false positive bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24447/c-core-check-false-positive-c26496-c26493.html) in the past. It is not of the same type as in the question, and was fixed last year anyways.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Hm, trying to make an example forced me into rethingking myself... Assuming `std::scoped_lock` did not exist, and `std::lock_guard` not either. We'd have to use `std::unique_lock` then, would we have it const? If so, we'd express with that the lock must not be lost as long as the object exists. Good point...

Comment: By the way, the always const philosophy is badly supported by the language. Why are variables not const by default and are made mutable on need by an equally named keyword (and yes, I know this originates from C, but then same question there as well...)?