How const std::unique_lock or const std::shared_lock would work
I have recently started learning about different locking mechanisms in C++. I am curious to know how would a const lock works.
std::mutex m;
int a = 10;
void func(){
  const std::unique_lock lck(m);
  a += 10;
  std::cout << "a: " << a << "\n";
}

If I have a function like below, what difference would it make if I use or not use const ?
Is it even valid or recommended to use const std::unique_lock ? If yes, what use-case of this could be there?

There should be no difference, other than the inability to call some (non-const) member functions.

Making it const will prevent calling methods like try_lock, try_lock_for etc. (i.e. non const ones). As far as I know it is not common or recommended to have it const, although if you only use it for releasing the mutex in the destructor (as in your code example), it should work.

@wohlstad yes thats what exactly i was thinking. I am also more inclined towards not using const with locks

I must admit that I make every local variable const if I don't have a reason to not to do so. I see this is a kind of defensive programming. Non-mutating objects may lower the complexity of the code and may contribute to the maintainability...

It comes down to style and readability but making locks const is a good indication to any future reader of the code that the lock stays active for its entire lifetime. Basically, you don't have to spend time looking for an unlock, move, or use with condition variables. Then again, if a unique_lock stays active, it may as well be a simpler lock_guard

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59281205/5754656 https://stackoverflow.com/q/52242157/5754656

It is valid to use const with a std::unique_lock or std::shared_lock, however, it somewhat defeats the purpose of using these types.
std::shared_lock can be copied (and thus ownership shared with others) even when const, but std::unique_lock cannot be transferred elsewhere because the move constructor takes std::unique_lock<M>&&, and such an rvalue reference cannot bind to a const lock.
It should also be noted that any member functions such as lock(), unlock(), etc. which don't work on a const object cannot be called.
Instead of const std::unique_lock, prefer to use std::scoped_lock if you really insist on using const here.
In general, std::unique_lock tells the reader that you're interested in transferring ownership, and that would be misleading if you don't actually do that.
Personally, I recommend never making mutexes, locks, and other threading primitives const, as they never play the role of a "constant" in code.
It's also not obvious whether they work with const; otherwise you wouldn't have asked this question :)

Note: If you're not using C++17, you can also use std::lock_guard. However, this kind of lock should be avoided because it's obsoleted by std::scoped_lock.

I don't agree that std::lock_guard is "obsoleted by std::scoped_lock" and "should be avoided". I think it's a good practice to use the simplest tool for the job (i.e., std::lock_guard) when you have only one mutex. See Howard Hinnant's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60172828/1458097

@heapunderrun well, there's no consensus on the issue. Different people have different opinions. One issue with std::lock_guard is that it may slow compilation because more different class templates get instantiated. It also means that newcomers to your codebase need to learn both std::scoped_lock for the N-mutex case and std::lock_guard for the simple case, which complicates things. It's much easier to just purge the old type when working on a team. The bug where someone writes std::scoped_lock lock; is also relatively harmless. It just does nothing.
